# displaying updated_at gives error in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I´m trying to display the time when user updated his post with

```
<%= current_user.hwaters(:updated_at).to_s  %>
```

`User` `has_many :hwaters`

and `Hwaters` `belongs_to :user`

Why is this not working?

Comment: Always define "not working"

Comment: And always show the error message.

Comment: Sorry, guys I´ll be more precise in my next post, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood right what you want to do, I think you could try:

```
<%= current_user.hwaters.map(&:updated_at).join(', ') %>
```

By the way, you could read more about Rails Active Record Associations [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) to understand how it works.

Comment: thank you @kitz this worked like a charm, i´ll read about Rails Active Record Associations. I´m new to rails and so much to learn.  I used the pluck , it works like magic

Comment: Watch out when using pluck - it might lead to a serious N+1 issue when used incorrectly. Should be all fine here though.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to show the updated_at of an one to many association. This will not work, you will need to select one of the items and show that timestamp (or show all of them as described by kitz)

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question "Why is this not working?":

According to the [Active Record Associations guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference),

> 4.3.1.1 collection(force_reload = false)
>
> The collection method returns an **array** of all of the associated objects. If there are no associated objects, it returns an empty array.

(emphasis added).

So, when you're calling

```
current_user.hwaters
```

You're receiving an instance of Array. And when you're calling

```
current_user.hwaters(:updated_at)
```

the array doesn't know how to respond to `(:updated_at)`. So, it falls over on the floor, kicking and screaming, and throws a big tantrum.

The other answers on "How to make this work" are quite nice. And generous. You should follow them. And accept them. And upvote them. And spread love across the universe.

Comment: thank you @jvillian  this is very informative and helps me understand

Comment: Sure thing and glad to be helpful. Please don't forget to show some upvote love.

Comment: I up voted, I belive I need 15 rep points for it to show.... I lost couple of rep points on that question of mine :)

Comment: Just to clarify - rails documentation is lying here a little as it is not returning array, but ActiveRecord::Relation object. It is using method_missing magic to delegate methods to the internal `@records` array, however it is great to know the difference here.

Comment: @BroiSatse. Well, said. That's sort of `102` stuff and I figured we were still in the `101` session. But, you're dead right.